# Extract date (yyyy/mm/dd) from a timestamp in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, timestamp

I want to extract just the date part from a timestamp in PostgreSQL.

I need it to be a postgresql `DATE` type so I can insert it into another table that expects a `DATE` value.

For example, if I have `2011/05/26 09:00:00`, I want `2011/05/26`

**I tried casting, but I only get 2011:**

```
timestamp:date
cast(timestamp as date)
```

**I tried `to_char()` with `to_date()`:**

```
SELECT to_date(to_char(timestamp, 'YYYY/MM/DD'), 'YYYY/MM/DD') 
FROM val3 WHERE id=1;
```

**I tried to make it a function:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testing() RETURNS void AS '
DECLARE i_date DATE;
BEGIN
    SELECT to_date(to_char(val1, "YYYY/MM/DD"),"YYYY/MM/DD") 
      INTO i_date FROM exampTable WHERE id=1;
    INSERT INTO foo(testd) VALUES (i);
END
```

What is the best way to extract date (yyyy/mm/dd) from a timestamp in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 630, accepted):

You can cast your timestamp to a date by suffixing it with `::date`.  Here, in psql, is a timestamp:

```
# select '2010-01-01 12:00:00'::timestamp;
      timestamp      
---------------------
 2010-01-01 12:00:00
```

Now we'll cast it to a date:

```
wconrad=# select '2010-01-01 12:00:00'::timestamp::date;
    date    
------------
 2010-01-01
```

On the other hand you can use `date_trunc` function. The difference between them is that the latter returns the same data type like `timestamptz` keeping your time zone intact (if you need it).

```
=> select date_trunc('day', now());
       date_trunc
------------------------
 2015-12-15 00:00:00+02
(1 row)
```

Comment: doesn't work, just tried "select '2010-01-01 12:00:00'::timestamp::date;"  .  it returns just year 2011. i had already tried date(timestamp) and (timestamp)::date but i only get the year part in return not the full date that i need.

Comment: @kerenk, Now *that's* odd.  Did you try it in psql?

Comment: @keren, psql is a command-line utility--you're not using it (but do consider it).  When you execute the query in pgadmin3, look at the data output pane.  You can resize the columns; the default column size is too short to show the entire date and shows only the year.  Use your mouse to expand that column and you should see the whole thing.

Comment: omg you're right. i feel so stupid. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: One case I ran into where this doesn't work is in Squirrel. With this syntax, Squirrel will give you an input box to input parameter values for parameter ":date".

Comment: It is helpful.. I am also using *pgsql* right now.. It is hammering on my head. Let me try this solution... :) +1 in advance.

Comment: Didn't work for me in Hibernate native queries. Solution (with the now() function): `CAST(NOW() AS date)`

Comment: Beware of `::date` as it can get in conflict with parameters (`:myParameter`) in siome cases.

Comment: It works fine, i got a small error, but i was using a column alias like this, **column as c1::timestamp::date** , then i change it to **column::timestamp::date as c1** and it worked fine.

Answer (score 152):

Use the [date](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/functions-datetime.html) function:

```
select date(timestamp_field) from table
```

From a character field representation to a date you can use:

```
select date(substring('2011/05/26 09:00:00' from 1 for 10));
```

Test code:

```
create table test_table (timestamp_field timestamp);
insert into test_table (timestamp_field) values(current_timestamp);
select timestamp_field, date(timestamp_field) from test_table;
```

Test result:

[image: pgAdmin result]

[image: pgAdmin result wide]

Comment: i've tried that but i only get 2011 in return instead of the full date like 2011/05/26

Comment: I realized you are not working with a timetamp data type.  Revised to work with a string representation of a timestamp in the format you provided.

Comment: How are you executing the sql?  psql?

Comment: i'm using pgAdmin III postgresSQL

Comment: I noticed when I perform a test in pgAdmin III the 'date' column is only wide enough to display the year.  Grab the column handle and expand the column to see the full date.

Answer (score 27):

In postgres simply :

```
TO_CHAR(timestamp_column, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as submission_date
```

Answer (score 23):

Have you tried to cast it to a date, with `<mydatetime>::date` ?

Comment: This works just fine.  As noted in the comments on Wayne Conrad's answer, keren was led astray by an excessively narrow column in pgAdmin's output pane.

Answer (score 14):

This works for me in python 2.7

```
 select some_date::DATE from some_table;
```

Answer (score 13):

Just do `select date(timestamp_column)` and you would get the only the date part.
Sometimes doing `select timestamp_column::date` may return `date 00:00:00` where it doesn't remove the `00:00:00` part. But I have seen `date(timestamp_column)` to work perfectly in all the cases. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

```
CREATE TABLE sometable (t TIMESTAMP, d DATE);
INSERT INTO sometable SELECT '2011/05/26 09:00:00';
UPDATE sometable SET d = t; -- OK
-- UPDATE sometable SET d = t::date; OK
-- UPDATE sometable SET d = CAST (t AS date); OK
-- UPDATE sometable SET d = date(t); OK
SELECT * FROM sometable ;
          t          |     d      
---------------------+------------
 2011-05-26 09:00:00 | 2011-05-26
(1 row)
```

Another test kit:

```
SELECT pg_catalog.date(t) FROM sometable;
    date    
------------
 2011-05-26
(1 row)

SHOW datestyle ;
 DateStyle 
-----------
 ISO, MDY
(1 row)
```

Comment: i just tried yours in pgAdmin but d only has 2011 not full date which i needed! :(

Comment: @keren: what about SELECT pg_catalog.date('2011/05/26 09:00:00'); ?

Comment: maybe it has something to do with formatting the output value. I'm thinking that the return value probably has day and month in there , but its just not shown on scree?

Comment: typing in SHOW datestyle ;  game me "ISO, DMY"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `date_trunc('day', field)`.

```
select date_trunc('day', data_gps) as date_description from some_table;
```