# Comparing a Date to the Datetime Created_at in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I'm trying to do things like so:

```
today = Date.today - 1
todaysReport = Report.where(:created_at => today).find_by_user_id(user.id)
```

The problem is created_at is a datetime, so it won't find any matches..Any suggestions?

Comment: `Date.today - 1` will evaluate to *yesterday*.   Either remove the `-1` or change the three instances of "today" to "yesterday"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
yesterday = Time.now - 1.day
user = User.find(user_id)

todaysReport = user.reports.where(["created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?", yesterday.beginning_of_day, yesterday.end_of_day])
```

Comment: @dex, @elliot...i dont know if this works for postgres, but this works for mysql..`user.report.where(["DATE(created_at) = ?", Date.today - 1])`

Comment: @rubyprince You want to steer away from DB-specific functions like DATE(). Also, this query will be slow since it must run DATE() on every record in the table.

Comment: Why is using ruby ranges in rails queries so unpopular? I prefer: `.where(created_at: yesterday.beginning_of_day..yesterday.end_of_day)`

Comment: @MikeCampbell at the time I actually didn't realize you could do this. I like it better.

Answer (score 16):

In postgres, you can cast a timestamp as a date. For example:

`Report.where("created_at::date = ?", Date.today - 1)`

[Extract date (yyyy/mm/dd) from a timestamp in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133107/extract-date-yyyy-mm-dd-from-a-timestamp-in-postgresql)

Comment: SQLite3::SQLException: unrecognized token: ":": ? this is what I use, **  Note.where("created_at::date= ? and user_id= ? ",  day , current_user.id)**

Answer (score 6):

You need to compare against a range from one midnight to the next.
Also, this is a good candidate for making your own class method
for higher flexibility.

```
class Report
  # All reports created on the specified Date
  def self.created_on(date)
    where(['created_at >= ? AND created_at < ?', date, date + 1])
  end
end

# Find all reports created yesterday by our user
Report.created_on(Date.today - 1).where(:user_id => user.id)
```

Comment: I like this! I should be adding beginning_of_day and end_of_day to the date var though right?

Comment: @Elliot: No need. The dates will be converted to datetimes with the time part set to midnight behind the scenes.

Answer (score 4):

In **Rails 5.1** and greater, you can use [`all_day`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-all_day) instance method like this:

```
today = Date.today - 1
todaysReport = Report.where(created_at: today.all_day).find_by_user_id(user.id)
```

Comment: Even though the OP was about Rails 3.1, this was very helpful to me. I didn't know about all_day.

Answer (score 1):

It can also be TimeWithZone if time zone specified in application config. To get Date to TimeWithZone you have to do like Date.today.to_time.in_time_zone.

Answer (score -5):

Have you tried using `#to_datetime`, which Rails adds to the `Date` and `Time` classes?

```
Report.where(:created_at => today.to_datetime).find_by_user_id(user.id)
```

Actually surprised AR doesn't handle this for you.

Comment: wouldn't it be trying to match on a time when I'm only trying to match the day?

Comment: The only problem with this is that he probably actually wants a range, which is why it doesn't work. AR should not generate an error as he has it now.