# DATE_FORMAT() equivalent in PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have this query in mysql

```
SELECT * 
FROM `calendar` 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(startTime, "%Y-%m-%d") = '2010-04-29'
```

How can i convert to Postgresql query?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, the query in `MYSQL` which uses `DATE_FORMAT()` converts date into string. If you want to compare it with date, don't use `DATE_FORMAT()` but instead `DATE()`. Try this, in `PostgreSQL`, casting timestamp into date,

```
SELECT * 
FROM   "calendar"
WHERE  "startTime"::date = '2010-04-29'
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/12c3c/3)
- [*other source*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133107/extract-dateyyyy-mm-dd-from-timestamp-postgresql)

Comment: Somehow my query is not returning the correct results. In my database coulmn currently my date is stored as this `2012-10-05 09:00:00+08 ` when i try "startTime"::date = '2012-10-05' i am not getting any result

Comment: what is the data type of `startTime` column?

Comment: datetime , i think i have problem somewhere in my joins , i will check that. thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM calendar
WHERE starttime::date = '2010-04-29'
```