# PgSQL turning day-of-year back into date

Tags: postgresql, date

I am trying to determine how to turn a day-of-year back into a date in PgSQL.  When I do this

```
select date '2013-01-01' + interval '53 days'
```

I get a timestamp:

```
"2013-02-23 00:00:00"
```

So how come when I do any of the following

```
select extract(date from (date '2013-01-01' + interval '53 days'))

select extract(date from (select date '2013-01-01' + interval '53 days'))
```

I get "ERROR:  timestamp units "date" not recognized"?  Besides the why, how can I do what I want, which is to only get the date portion of the result of the original operation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133107/extract-date-yyyy-mm-dd-from-a-timestamp-in-postgresql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
select (date '2013-01-01' + interval '53 days')::date
```

or

```
select cast(date '2013-01-01' + interval '53 days' as date)
```

[PostgreSQL's standard SQL function "extract()"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) *will* operate on timestamps, but a) "date" isn't a valid argument to extract(), and b) it returns subfields, not a collection of subfields. Conceptually, a date consists of a collection of three subfields: year, month, and day.

```
select extract(year from current_timestamp),
       extract(month from current_timestamp),
       extract(day from current_timestamp),
       -- Concatenate and cast to type "date".
       (extract(year from current_timestamp) || '-' || 
       extract(month from current_timestamp) || '-' ||
       extract(day from current_timestamp))::date
```

Comment: OK thanks.  That works.  So what was wrong with my concept?  If the date + interval construction returns a timestamp, why won't the extract function operate on that?

Comment: @Steve: Expanded the answer.