# Postgresql complains when interval is result of string concatenation

Tags: postgresql, date, casting, intervals

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113372/pgsql-turning-day-of-year-back-into-date) to convert a (date + interval) into a date. Only in my case the date and the interval are strings that are the result of slice&dice of other strings. The problem is that it works when I construct the string for the `date` but not for the `interval`.

So, the following statements work:

```
SELECT (date '2013-01-01');
SELECT (interval '53 days');
SELECT (date '2013-01-01' + interval '53 days');
```

Now I want to synthesize the strings that are passed after `date` and `interval` by `substring`-ing some other string (think stored procedure where we operate on a passed parameter):

This works for `date`:

```
SELECT date (substring('2015015' from 1 for 4)||'-01-01')::text;
```

But it fails for `interval`:

```
SELECT interval (substring('2015015' from 5)||' days')::text;
```

with error message:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "substring"
```

It actually works if I cast explicitly to `interval` either with `CAST(x as INTERVAL)` or equivalently with `x::interval`:

```
SELECT CAST((substring('2015015' from 5)||' days')::text AS INTERVAL);
```

or equivalently:

```
SELECT ((substring('2015015' from 5)||' days')::text)::interval;
```

Why does the `date TEXT` work regardless of how the `TEXT` is placed there, but the same with `interval` only works with direct text, but not with synthesized one.

I'm on Postgres 9.4.

Comment: please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376350/postgresql-how-to-concat-interval-value-2-days

Comment: You may want to use the `make_date` and `make_interval` functions instead of doing string concatenation and casting to a date/interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `date` is actually a function in PostgreSQL. There is an `interval` function too, but [you need to quote it](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS):

```
SELECT "interval"(substring('2015015' from 5)||' days');
```

> It is also possible to specify a type cast using a function-like syntax:
>
> ```
> typename ( expression )
> ```
>
> However, this only works for types whose names are also valid as function names. For example, `double precision` cannot be used this way, but the equivalent `float8` can. Also, the names `interval`, `time`, and `timestamp` can only be used in this fashion **if they are double-quoted, because of syntactic conflicts**. Therefore, the use of the function-like cast syntax leads to inconsistencies and should probably be avoided.
>
> The function-like syntax is in fact just a function call. When one of the two standard cast syntaxes is used to do a run-time conversion, it will internally invoke a registered function to perform the conversion. By convention, these conversion functions have the same name as their output type, and thus the "function-like syntax" is nothing more than a direct invocation of the underlying conversion function. Obviously, this is not something that a portable application should rely on.

(Bold emphasis is mine.)

`date()` may be an exception here, most database vendors support something like that.

However, it seems you might build your `date()` query wrong too, because

```
SELECT date (substring('2015015' from 1 for 4)||'-01-01')::text;
```

will first convert `'2015-01-01'` (from `text`) to `date`, then to `text`. This syntax has nothing to do with the [`date` literals](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-GENERIC). Those can only expressed like this:

```
SELECT date '<constant string without any expressions>';
```

> To avoid syntactic ambiguity, the `type 'string'` syntax can only be used to specify the type of a simple literal constant. Another restriction on the `type 'string'` syntax is that it does not work for array types; use `::` or `CAST()` to specify the type of an array constant.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem of parenthesis, as you cannot have this:

> SELECT interval ('015 days')::text

Try with cast instead:

> SELECT (substring('2015015' from 5)||' days')::interval::text