# JasperReports not converting postgresql timestamp to simple date

Tags: jasper-reports, date-parsing

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133107/extract-date-yyyy-mm-dd-from-a-timestamp-in-postgresql) question which is similar to my question, but however the workaround still gave me an error.

I have an sql query string like this in my .jrxml file

```
<queryString>
        <![CDATA[select sl_no,cast(action_on as date) from action_history]]>
</queryString>
```

I am using the Eclipse plugin JasperStudio for designing the template and am using PostgreSql for my database. Now this query is fetching data properly as expected.

My action_on is a java.sql.Timestamp type.
`<field name="action_on" class="java.sql.Timestamp">`
 I only want the date like `22/08/15` or `22/08/2015` to be printed and don't want the time to be printed, so when I try casting or using `action_on::date` , I get `22/08/15 12:00 AM`  printed with the time **always** 12:00 AM. What perplexes me more is that when I try this command on my terminal , it doesn't give me the time  and only the unformatted date!
Is there a workaround for this?

**EDIT** 
I changed `<field name="action_on" class="java.sql.Timestamp">` to `<field name="action_on" class="java.lang.String">` and I get the date `2015-08-22` !
Is there a way to now format this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other solution is to **not format** in query (but to format when you output) using `pattern` attribute on the `textField` tag

```
<textField pattern="dd-MM-yyyy">
    <reportElement x="0" y="o" width="100" height="20"uuid="b8baea82-84c4-42fa-bccd-62abc96eeded"/>
    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{action_on}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

The main **advantage** is that if you export to for example [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) the column will be correctly filled with a **date object** (hence a user of excel can filter/sort/format on the date object).

Comment: Accepting the answer for the advantage part ! Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

I got it resolved myself , so I am posting my solution to my problem . A better solution is obviously welcome!

I converted the field type to String i.e did the `EDIT` to the question. To format the date you can now use
`<![CDATA[select sl_no,to_char(action_on,'dd-MM-yyyy') as my_date from action_history]]>`

Don't forget to replace every **following** instance of declaring or using `action_on` in your field declarations by `my_date` !

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot.