# Joining 3 Tables Inner & Left

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join, inner-join

Can someone verify if my query is producing the intended results that I am hoping for?

I am using PostgreSQL.

```
 SELECT sold_at
, quantity
, returned_at
, name
, price
FROM sales
LEFT JOIN returns
ON sales.order_id=returns.order_id
JOIN  products
ON sales.product_id=products.product_id
WHERE name LIKE '%sock%'
ORDER by sold_at ASC
```

```
sold_at | quantity | returned_at | name | price

2015-06-01 | 8 | |socks-toeless | 15
2015-06-01 | 7 | 2015-06-08| socks-flat | 15
```

My goal is for the output to include all sock purchases from the sales table (regardless of whether or not it was returned), and have a column that shows whether the sock order was returned that is populated with a date if it was returned and is blank if the item was not returned.

The name of the product (i.e., 'sock') comes from the product table.

Comment: What database are you using? You might just need to change "LEFT JOIN" into "LEFT OUTER JOIN".

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: Then OUTER is implied, so I guess your query is fine. Is it not working like you expect?

Comment: Your query seems to be fine...

Comment: Sample data as well as desired results would help.  Your query is unlikely to be producing the results that you intend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your query looks like it should work as intended.

Comment: Thanks! Within Postgres how would I select only the date from a datetime variable? i manually deleted it above but the DATETIME actually includes hours mins secs.

Comment: A simple cast to a "date" works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133107/extract-date-yyyy-mm-dd-from-a-timestamp-in-postgresql
Depending on what you want, you also can use PostgreSQL functions like "extract" or "date_trunc".

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not describe what the tables look like.  I would expect the `returns` table to include the product, so I would anticipate a query that looks more like this:

```
SELECT s.*, p.name,
       (case when r.product_id is null then 0 else 1 end) as IsReturnFlag
FROM sales s JOIN
     products p
     ON s.product_id = p.product_id LEFT JOIN
     returns r
     ON s.order_id = r.order_id AND
        s.product_id = r.product_id
WHERE p.name LIKE '%sock%';
```

Comment: *Sales table -- sold_at, order_id, product_id, quantity, user_id

*Products table -- product_id, name, price

*Returns table -- returned_at, order_id

Comment: @am340 . . . How do you know what product was returned, if the order contains multiple products?