# How to cast Timestamp to Date

Tags: postgresql, casting, timestamp

In a view, I'm casting a timestamp without timezone to date.

Looks to me like any of these should work:

```
Cast("Orders"."OrderDate" as Date),
Date("Orders"."OrderDate"),
"Orders"."OrderDate"::Date,
```

but they all give the error

```
cannot change data type of view column "OrderDate" from timestamp without time zone to date
```

Postgres 11
pgAdmin 4.9

Comment: try this previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133107/extract-date-yyyy-mm-dd-from-a-timestamp-in-postgresql

Comment: Did that. It recommends the second and third approaches I tried above. Which don't work for me. Can't change data type to date

Comment: Are you trying to change the definition of an existing view?  If so, you can't change the type of a column.  You will need to drop the view and create it again.

Comment: @Jeremy That was it. Then you have to close any open queries, refresh the list of views, reopen the queries. Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the type of a column in a view. You will need to drop the view along with all of the objects that depends on that view and create them again.

Comment: This was the reason that none of the standard answers were working.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> select date_trunc('day', now());
> ```
>
> ```
> | date_trunc             |
> | :--------------------- |
> | 2019-08-31 00:00:00+01 |
> ```

> ```
> select date_trunc('day', now())::date;
> ```
>
> ```
> | date_trunc |
> | :--------- |
> | 2019-08-31 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=98fa7fbfc114d91f26ee421882591a8c)*

Comment: I get the same result you do for the first query. Trims the time, returns just the date.

Comment: But the second query returns the same error as the other approaches. Can't convert to Date

Comment: what version of postgres? as you can see it worked for me (click the "here" in the answer) that s a live demo. & Consider building a fiddle of your own to replicate the issue you face.